# egit clone fails over https

Tags: eclipse, git, ssl, egit

I am unable to clone via egit over https. I get 500 Internal server error and am seeing the below error in eclipse log

```
. org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: 
    https://my.server.com/git/testing.git: 500 Internal Server Error
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:178)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:125)
        at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.CloneOperation.run(CloneOperation.java:155)
        at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.AbstractGitCloneWizard.executeCloneOperation(AbstractGitCloneWizard.java:431)
        at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.AbstractGitCloneWizard.access$2(AbstractGitCloneWizard.java:424)
        at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.AbstractGitCloneWizard$6.run(AbstractGitCloneWizard.java:403)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
    Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://my.server.com/git/testing.git: 500 Internal Server Error
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.doFetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:370)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp$SmartHttpFetchConnection.doFetch(TransportHttp.java:747)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.fetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:301)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.fetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:291)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.fetchObjects(FetchProcess.java:247)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:160)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:122)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1108)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:128)
        ... 7 more
    Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://my.server.com/git/testing.git: 500 Internal Server Error
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp$Service.openResponse(TransportHttp.java:843)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp$MultiRequestService.execute(TransportHttp.java:945)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp$Service$HttpExecuteStream.read(TransportHttp.java:871)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.io.UnionInputStream.read(UnionInputStream.java:145)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.io.TimeoutInputStream.read(TimeoutInputStream.java:112)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.IO.readFully(IO.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PacketLineIn.readLength(PacketLineIn.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PacketLineIn.readString(PacketLineIn.java:138)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PacketLineIn.readACK(PacketLineIn.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.negotiate(BasePackFetchConnection.java:654)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.doFetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:356)
        ... 15 more
```

I see the below error in apache log

```
 [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1925): OpenSSL: I/O error, 5 bytes expected to read on BIO#7f72e9617660 [mem: 7f72e96060a3]
[info] [ (70014)End of file found: SSL input filter read failed.
 [error]  (70014)End of file found: Error reading request entity data
```

I am totally struck with for the past 2 weeks. Help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Does cloning with the same URL work using native Git?

Comment: the same url work with http. i am not using git protocol

Comment: No, I mean when you use `git clone https://...` on the console using the original Git implementation in C (instead of EGit).

Comment: Git bash works fine  with https when i give http verify= false, for both clone and push

Comment: Can you try the configuration `http.sslVerify=false`?

Comment: I tried that too. but no luck

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39278/discussion-between-user2164525-and-robinst)